# In jquery how can i use .change to enable a button immediately?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a simple form with a text input and a button disabled, this button can be enabled if i write on input text, keyup() is the best way but when i use right click and paste this event isn't called and doesn't trigger that event. So i tried event change(), it's work but not immediately, i must unfocus the input text for have the button enabled. How can i enable this button immediately with copy and paste?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_input').bind('keyup paste click', function () {
        if ($('#id_input').val().length === 6 ){
            $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
        else
        $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });

});
```

Comment: Your code should work fine (and does: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/2csnt8h0/). Please add the relevant HTML to the question so we can try and recreate a working example of the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rory is right that your code should work in general especially if you paste using Ctrl + V.
I assume that you experience the issue only if you paste using right-click and then select Paste from the context menu.
Try to monitor the property changes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id_input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    if ($('#id_input').val().length === 6) {
      $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else
      $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `onpaste` event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#id_input').bind('keyup onpaste click', function () {
    if ($('#id_input').val().length === 6 ){
      $('#btnSubmit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
      $('#btnSubmit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: i tried but nothing, it work with .bind('input propertychange')